# Is using a complex function in initializer list to initialize const member a good design?

Tags: c++, constructor

recently I was looking at old horrible mess of a class... 
Long story short it would help with thread safety if one member was const.
But the problem is that member is initialized in ctor, and it is nontrivial construction. So I was thinking about creating a special init function for that member. Is that a good decision. 
Small super simple example(real code is full of conditionals :) and try-s)
:

```
class ComplexInitList
{
std::pair<double,double> init_pair(const int first, const int second)
{
    if ((first == 0) || (second == 0))
       throw std::invalid_argument("div by 0");
    return std::make_pair(1.0/first, 1.0/second);
}
const std::pair<double,double> p;
public:
 ComplexInitList(int a, int b):p(init_pair(a,b))
{
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << std::endl;
}  
};
```

Comment: Whether a member is const or not has no effect on thread safety; the only issue is whether you modify it or not.  (But IMHO, your solution still makes sense.)

Comment: if it is const you can read it without mutex(In C++11)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: if it's non-const you can read it without the mutex, provided that it is not modified. `const` tells the compiler to help make sure it's not modified. And note that even if it is `const`, you can't read it without sequencing if the object is created in one thread and then accessed from a different thread. It's just that you only need one pair of ops to be sequenced (the creation and the read), whereas if there were writes to a non-const object they would need to be sequenced with respect to the read too.

Comment: yeah I know, but tnx for explaining it nicely... what i said in the post is true but not precise:"it would help with thread safety if one member was const"  should have been : "it would make thread safe design easier because on const memeber after initalization you dont need mutex". Ofc there is a race condition if you do ComplexInitList* ptr= new ComplexInitList(); and some other thread is doing dumb spin wait (while ptr==0{}//use ptr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a common and accepted solution to this problem. If possible, consider making the init function static, so that unexpected semantics of operations on object under construction (such as behaviour of virtual calls) can't kick in.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but to add for any new search-engine'ers:

If `init_pair` isn't going to be used anywhere else I find a lambda to be the most elegant way of solving this problem:

```cpp
class ComplexInitList
{
const std::pair<double,double> p;

public:
 ComplexInitList(const int a, const int b) : 
    p([](const int a, const int b) {
        if ((first == 0) || (second == 0)) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("div by 0");
        }

        return std::make_pair(1.0/first, 1.0/second);
    }()) // <-- Note the extra '()' with immediately calls the lambda!
{
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << std::endl;
} 

};
```

Answer (score 1):

To initialize a const data member the only way is to initialize it in `member initializer list`.

`p` is a const, so it can be initialized to a value, but it can't be assigned a value. Conceptually, calling a constructor creates an object before the code
within the brackets is executed. Thus `calling ComplexInitList(int a, int b):p(init_pair(a,b))` cause the program first to allocate space for member `p`.

Then program flow enters
the brackets and uses ordinary assignment to place values into the allocated space. So if you want to initialize a const data member, you have to initialize it in `member initializer list`